# Watchman Version Showing 0.0.0. Preventing npm start on React Native App

Tags: react-native, macos, homebrew, watchman

I am trying to develop a react native application on MacOS, but I have been running into issues with installing watchman onto the machine. I have been running the command `brew install watchman` and whenever I enter the command `watchman version` the output displays `version: 0.0.0`. However, directly after running the first installation command over again, I see `Warning: watchman 2022.06.06.00 is already installed and up-to-date` which is really confusing me.

I have tried various different troubleshooting techniques such as uninstalling and reinstalling watchman, instead of using brew I attempted using `sudo port install watchman` with MacPorts, removing the .watchmanconfig file and re-creating it, and lastly restarting my device, but none of these solutions have seemed to work for me.

Whenever, I open my react native project and run the command `npm start`, this is the output that I see,

```
jest-haste-map: Watchman crawl failed. Retrying once with node crawler.
  Usually this happens when watchman isn't running. Create an empty `.watchmanconfig` file in your project's root folder or initialize a git or hg repository in your project.
```

...

```
watchmanResponse: {
    error: 'std::__1::system_error: open: /Users/USER/Desktop/ReactNativeApp: Operation not permitted',
    version: '0.0.0'
  }
```

This error message ends the `npm start` and because of this, I am unable to run `npm run ios` and continue with the development of the application. If anyone happens to know of any fixes or has experienced this before I would appreciate it if you share how I can resolve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We can resolved this when we put our project outside from those folder Desktop,Download and Document
then run

npm start

It will be work
thanks

Comment: Where exactly should I store it then? I tried putting it in my iCloud directory but that didn’t seem to solve the problem either. I am still getting a version 0.0.0 when watchman attempts to run.

Comment: you need to put your project inside user name directory